How to say "to keep" in latin
How would one say "to keep" as in "you are what you keep" or "you are what you hold" in relation to money.
The phrasing is to serve as a reminder that you are not what you spend but rather what you keep/hold.
Any suggestions with regards to specific words to convey the meaning or the whole phrase would be much appreciated.
Thanks

To keep or hold is often expressed by tenere or servare, which come with a few derived variants each, like continere, conservare, etc. For keeping as opposed to spending, I would choose retinere, e.g. es quod retines, non quod expendis.

In your quote, is es "are" or "eat"? It makes an amount of sense either way.

@JoonasIlmavirta Etiam sunt qui dicant: es quod es. (Praesertim Germani, sequentes philosophum haereticissimum Ludovicum Feuerbach, qui suam intelligentiam scientiae nutrimentorum ita complexus est, ut dixit: hominem esse quod esse!)
